# Creating table in PhpWord

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpword

Everything is working fine, but I am have really tried to make a table in phpword without white spacing with below the text inside the table. Please help me out forming this situation.

This is my code....

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$phpWord->getCompatibility()->setOoxmlVersion(14);
$phpWord->getCompatibility()->setOoxmlVersion(15);

$targetFile = "./global/uploads/";
$filename = $news['CompanyDetails']['QuotationCode'].' Quotation For '.$news['CompanyDetails']['CompanyName'].'.docx';

$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->getStyle()->setBreakType('continuous');
$header = $section->addHeader();
$header->headerTop(10);



$section->addImage(base_url('images/qoutlogo.jpg'), array('align'=>'center' ,'topMargin' => -5));

$section->addTextBreak(-5);
$center = $phpWord->addParagraphStyle('p2Style', array('align'=>'center','marginTop' => 1));
$section->addText('this is my name',array('bold' => true,'underline'=>'single','name'=>'TIMOTHYfont','size' => 14),$center);
$section->addTextBreak(-.5);

$section->addText('Tel:    00971-55-25553443 Fax: 00971-55- 2553443',array('name'=>'Times New Roman','size' => 13),$center);
$section->addTextBreak(-.5);
$section->addText('Quotation',array('bold' => true,'underline'=>'single','name'=>'Times New Roman','size' => 16),$center);
$section->addTextBreak(-.5);
$tableStyle = array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '999999', 'afterSpacing' => 0, 'Spacing'=> 0, 'cellMargin'=>0  );
$styleCell = array('borderTopSize'=>1 ,'borderTopColor' =>'black','borderLeftSize'=>1,'borderLeftColor' =>'black','borderRightSize'=>1,'borderRightColor'=>'black','borderBottomSize' =>1,'borderBottomColor'=>'black' );
$fontStyle = array('italic'=> true, 'size'=>11, 'name'=>'Times New Roman','afterSpacing' => 0, 'Spacing'=> 0, 'cellMargin'=>0 );
$TfontStyle = array('bold'=>true, 'italic'=> true, 'size'=>11, 'name' => 'Times New Roman', 'afterSpacing' => 0, 'Spacing'=> 0, 'cellMargin'=>0);
$cfontStyle = array('allCaps'=>true,'italic'=> true, 'size'=>11, 'name' => 'Times New Roman','afterSpacing' => 0, 'Spacing'=> 0, 'cellMargin'=>0);
$noSpace = array('textBottomSpacing' => -1);
$table = $section->addTable('myOwnTableStyle',array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '999999', 'afterSpacing' => 0, 'Spacing'=> 0, 'cellMargin'=>0  ));
$table2 = $section->addTable('myOwnTableStyle');
$table->addRow(-0.5, array('exactHeight' => -5));
$countrystate = $news['CompanyDetails']['Country'].' - '.$news['CompanyDetails']['State'];
$table->addCell(2500,$styleCell)->addText('Date',$TfontStyle);
$table->addCell(6000,$styleCell)->addText($news['CompanyDetails']['Date'],$fontStyle);
$table->addCell(1500,$styleCell)->addText('Cust. Ref',$TfontStyle);
$table->addCell(2000,$styleCell)->addText($news['CompanyDetails']['Reference'],$fontStyle);
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(2500,$styleCell)->addText('Company Name',$TfontStyle);
$table->addCell(6000,$styleCell)->addText($news['CompanyDetails']['CompanyName'],$cfontStyle);
$table->addCell(1500,$styleCell)->addText('Tel',$TfontStyle);
$table->addCell(2000,$styleCell)->addText($news['CompanyDetails']['Tel'],$fontStyle);
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(2500,$styleCell)->addText('Country',$TfontStyle);
$table->addCell(6000,$styleCell)->addText($countrystate, $fontStyle);
$table->addCell(1500,$styleCell)->addText('Fax',$TfontStyle);
$table->addCell(2000,$styleCell)->addText($news['CompanyDetails']['Fex'],$fontStyle);
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(2500,$styleCell)->addText('Attn.',$TfontStyle);
$table->addCell(6000,$styleCell)->addText($news['CompanyDetails']['ContectPerson'].' '. $news['CompanyDetails']['Designation'].' '.$news['CompanyDetails']['MobileNum'],$fontStyle);
$table->addCell(1500,$styleCell)->addText('Email',$TfontStyle);
$table->addCell(2000,$styleCell)->addText($news['CompanyDetails']['Email'],$fontStyle);
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(2500,$styleCell)->addText('Subject',$TfontStyle);
$table->addCell(6000,$styleCell)->addText($news['CompanyDetails']['Subject'],$fontStyle);
$table->addCell(1500,$styleCell)->addText('From',$TfontStyle);
$table->addCell(2000,$styleCell)->addText($news['CompanyDetails']['From'],$fontStyle);
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(2500,$styleCell)->addText('Quotation No.',$TfontStyle);
$table->addCell(6000,$styleCell)->addText($news['CompanyDetails']['QuotationNum'],$fontStyle);
$table->addCell(1500,$styleCell)->addText('pages',$TfontStyle);
$table->addCell(2000,$styleCell)->addText($news['CompanyDetails']['Pages'],$fontStyle);

$section->addTextBreak(-1);
```

The result is this

[image]

but I required Like this (without white spacing or padding)

[image]

Comment: i think this is paragraph issue. because when the paragraph or single line is finish so then that spaces are visible. so please if so one can solve is issue and delete it this spacing after paragraph. i was try to find out but i didn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

Just add spaceAfter align value to 0 in every `addText` like:

```
$table->addCell(2500,$styleCell)->addText('Date',$TfontStyle,array('align' => 'left', 'spaceAfter' => 0));
```